# Foreign key constraints while dumping data

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql, mysql-error-1062

```
mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -h192.168.150.180 -uroot -p live pnlbus_stops | sed s/pnlbus_stops/bus_stops/g | mysql test
```

I am getting an error:
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1: Duplicate entry 'AN' for key 1

This is because bus_stops table in the test DB has foreign key constraints. How do I truncate the bus_stops table from test database in a SINGLE STATEMENT before inserting from "live" DB?

Comment: I have managed to solve it by adding echo "truncate table test.bus_stops" before mysqldump statement. But is there any better way?

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE? But I don't understand what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

put

```
set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

at the top of your dump file

and put

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

at the bottom of your dump file

Comment: I just re-read your question, I don't understand what you're trying to do either