# How to disable foreign key checks while migrating to google cloud sql due to circular references

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to migrate a production database to google cloud sql using the replication method described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external?). However, when importing the mysql dump file google cloud sql returns the error ''Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint''.

I've checked if there are any foreign key vialotions using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250775/force-innodb-to-recheck-foreign-keys-on-a-table-tables). However, there are no violations in the database.

Therefore, I've tracked down the problem to be due to [circular references](https://dzone.com/articles/dealing-with-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint). The only option seems to be to disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS during the import. However, I cannot find any method to set this flag.

Are there any recommendations on how to continue from here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

Comment: No it isn't. It targets the google cloud sql solution and specifically the described migration method that allows a transition with minimal downtime using the replication method.

Comment: In that case perhaps [drop FK's in the dump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010817/7032856) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS := NOT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS
;
```

Will toggle FK control in mysql.

Comment: My question is regarding google cloud sql. When migrating from an external server I see no possibility to perform such a query before the replication is successfull.