# Blanco page after uploading mysql file

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I try to upload a mysql file from another server.
But when i upload i get a white page when i upload .xml  or .zip

I need to say that it is Magento.

when i upload .sql i get this error:
Error   SQL query:

```
--
-- Constraints for table `eav_entity_attribute`
--
ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_attribute` ADD CONSTRAINT  `FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE` FOREIGN KEY (  `attribute_id` ) REFERENCES  `eav_attribute` ( `attribute_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
ADD CONSTRAINT  `FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP` FOREIGN KEY (  `attribute_group_id` ) REFERENCES  `eav_attribute_group` (  `attribute_group_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`geschenk_test`.`#sql-29b_7c74`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`)
>   REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: In your sql file you must set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
Look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429655/can-you-automatically-create-a-mysqldump-file-that-doesnt-enforce-foreign-key-c

Answer (score 0):

```
To restore a .sql file backup without constraint checking, simply add the following statements at the beginning of your .sql file:

SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;

At the end of the file, add the statements required to turn on constraint checking again:

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;


Please refer this http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database
```