# Mysqldump and the order of the tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I copy my database with `mysqldump - uroot -p pagesjaunes > E:\db.sql`
But when I try to execute `mysql pagesjaunes < db.sql` in my home pc I got error because `mysqldump` didn't put the tables with the right order in the file `db.sql`, tables without foreign key must be first for example.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fonction`;

CREATE TABLE `fonction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_qualite` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fonction_qualite_fk` (`id_qualite`),
  CONSTRAINT `fonction_qualite_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_qualite`) REFERENCES `qualite` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qualite`;
CREATE TABLE `qualite` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have to put `qualite` table first and it works but I have a lot of tables and there will be a lot of manual ordering.

So how can I handle this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i found the solution [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429655/can-you-automatically-create-a-mysqldump-file-that-doesnt-enforce-foreign-key-c) i was making a mistake, in file `E:\db.sql` generated i deleted the lines like that

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

i was thinking that it's just a comment but in reality they are instructions too.

Comment: that's actually a "conditional comment", telling MySQL to skip it if it's version is under 4.00.14

Answer (score 15):

You can't use `--compact` parameter of `mysqldump`, because it removes the information (comments) about foreign key dependency needed by mysql to recreate the tables later in the correct order.